# DLookup as ControlSource through VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

The below is in my control source and works:

```
=IIf(Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#]<>"",DLookUp("[CustomerSKU]","ItemCustomerSKU","ItemNumber = '" & Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#] & "' AND Customer = '" & Forms!GARF!customer & "' AND Company = '" & Forms!GARF!company & "' AND MarketingSeason = '" & DLookUp("[Code]","IDtoCode","ID = " & Forms!GARF!season_id) & "' AND Season = " & Forms!GARF!GARFyear),"")
```

I would like to assign it to another control source through VBA code like such:

```
Forms![GARF]![GARFsubForm]![SKU].ControlSource = (the above code)
```

`Forms![GARF]![GARFsubForm]![SKU]` is a column in a datasheet.

UPDATE:
With Remou's help I was able to come up with the below working solution:
The code is on the Form_Load event:

```
Forms![GARF]![GARFsubForm]![SKU].ControlSource = 
    "=IIf(Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#]<>''," 
    & "DLookUp(""[CustomerSKU]"",""ItemCustomerSKU"",""ItemNumber = '"" 
    & Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#] & ""' AND Customer = '" _
    & Forms!GARF!customer & "' AND Company = '" _
    & Forms!GARF!company & "' AND Season = " & Forms!GARF!GARFyear _
    & " AND MarketingSeason = '" 
    & DLookup("[Code]", "IDtoCode", "ID = " & Forms!GARF!season_id) & "'"")" & ",'')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems. This is what is returned by your string (broken into lines for clarity):

```
=IIf(Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#]<>"",
DLookUp([CustomerSKU],ItemCustomerSKU,"ItemNumber = '" 
& Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#] 
& " ' AND Customer = '" & Forms!GARF!customer 
& "' AND Company = '" & Forms!GARF!company 
& "' AND MarketingSeason = '" & DLookUp([Code],IDtoCode,"ID = " 
& Forms!GARF!season_id) & "' AND Season = " & Forms!GARF!GARFyear),"")
```

As you can see, these two are not quoted and they need to be:

```
DLookUp([CustomerSKU],ItemCustomerSKU,
```

There is an extra space here:

```
& " ' AND Customer = '" & Forms!GARF!customer
```

Is `finished_good_#` text similarly `season_id`?

It is often possible to use single quote ' instead of "", especially if you escape any occurrence of ' in the text with two ' eg ='O''Reilly'

EDIT

You are doing this in code, so it should be possible to make life easier, for example:

```
A = DLookup("[Code]", "IDtoCode", "ID = " & Forms!GARF!season_id)
B = "DLookUp(""[CustomerSKU]"",""ItemCustomerSKU"",""ItemNumber = '" _
    & Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#] & "' AND Customer = '" _
    & Forms!GARF!customer & "' AND Company = '" _
    & Forms!GARF!company & "' AND Season = " & Forms!GARF!GARFyear _
    & " AND MarketingSeason = '" & A & "'"")"


s = "=IIf(Forms!GARF!GARFsubForm![finished_good_#]<>''," & c & ",'')"

Debug.Print s
```

Comment: You are missing a few quotes on the second DLookUp. I have added an additional note to show how you could construct the strings separately.

Comment: @Bruno I updated my notes. BTW single letter variables are not suitable for finished code, but they are quite useful for testing.

Comment: Thanks. It is now showing the SKU# of the first record in all the rows of the CustomerSKU column. I updated my code.

Comment: @Bruno It seems that you are using a datasheet or a continuous form so that is the behaviour you can expect. Have you considered creating a suitable combo box that can be bound in some way to the relevant records of the continuous form?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by creating a combo box. If I manually set the control source to the above, the SKU# will be unique in each row corresponding to the ItemNumber.

Comment: In that case, create a query that includes the various columns (fields) and tables required to get both sku and item number in the output and use that as the row source of a combo with item number as the control source.